# Slide up/down both navbar and bottom toolbar when scrolling up/down (Like Pinterest App)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

Just like in the Pinterest app, when I scroll down/up I want my top navbar to slide up/down **and at the same time** my bottom toolbar to slide down/up.

Now, I've managed to make my top navigation bar hide and show when scrolling up/down using the code below. I'm trying to figure out how to simultaneously do the opposite with my bottom toolbar, but I just can't get it to work!

I'm kind of new at this so any suggestions would be most appreciated!

**jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var previousScroll = 0,
    headerOrgOffset = $('#header').height();

$('#header-wrap').height($('#header').height());

$(window).scroll(function () {
    var currentScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (currentScroll > headerOrgOffset) {
        if (currentScroll > previousScroll) {
            $('#header-wrap').slideUp();
        } else {
            $('#header-wrap').slideDown();
        }
    } 
    previousScroll = currentScroll;
}); });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on structure you provided in jsfiddle:

--HTML

```
<div id="header-wrap">
    <div id="header" class="clear">
        <nav><h1>Header</h1>another line<br/>another line
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer-wrap">
    <div id="footer" class="clear">
        <nav><h1>Footer</h1>another line<br/>another line
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

--CSS:

```
body {
    height: 1000px;
}

#header, #footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
    /*position: absolute;*/
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

#header {
    top: -20px;
    position: relative;
}

#header-wrap, #footer-wrap {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    padding: 0px;
    /*background-color: #e0e0e0;*/
}

#header-wrap {
    top: 0px; 
}

#footer-wrap {
    bottom: 0px; 
}
```

--JS

```
$(function() {
    var previousScroll = 0,
        headerOrgOffset = $('#header').height();

    //$('#header-wrap').height($('#header').height());

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var currentScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (currentScroll > headerOrgOffset) {
            if (currentScroll > previousScroll) {
                $('#header').slideUp("slow");
                $('#footer').slideDown("slow");
            } else {
                $('#header').slideDown("slow");
                $('#footer').slideUp("slow");
            }
        } 
        previousScroll = currentScroll;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however nothing happens to the footer on scroll down and on scroll up it slides up all the way with the header. my html structure can be found here: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/dXQbk/)

Comment: at the moment the footer is hidden by default and slides up when I scroll down, I need it to be visible on default, slide **down** when I scroll down and up when I scroll upp, i.e. opposite to the header. any suggenstions? thanks in advance!

Comment: in script comment/remove $("#footer").hide() line.

Is this fine with you? -> http://jsfiddle.net/dXQbk/9/

Comment: Works great! Just had to change to slideUp for the footer in the if-statement and the one in the else-statement to slideDown, like this jsfiddle.net/ashkanazadi/JVg6g/2 Thanks @quantum-robot!